# Python Data Crawler to MySQL DATABASE

Tags: python, mysql, sql, date, web-crawler

I am trying to retrieve some data that looks like this in the page source:
"date" : "2011-04-03T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 55182
}, {
"date" : "2011-04-10T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 23649
}, {
"date" : "2011-04-17T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 26064
}, {
"date" : "2011-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 18373
}, {
"date" : "2011-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 18073
}, {
"date" : "2011-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 15539
}, {
"date" : "2011-05-15T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 14562
}, {
"date" : "2011-05-22T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 18921
}, {
"date" : "2011-05-29T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 10849
}, {
"date" : "2011-06-05T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 5871
}, {
"date" : "2011-06-12T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 3804
}, {
"date" : "2011-06-19T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 8243
}, {
"date" : "2011-06-26T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 9688
}, {
"date" : "2011-07-03T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 11592
}, {
"date" : "2011-07-10T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 11508
}, {
"date" : "2011-07-17T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 10405
}, {
"date" : "2011-07-24T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 10080
}, {
"date" : "2011-07-31T00:00:00.000Z",
"rank" : 10392
}

I would like to retrieve this data from the website using a Python crawler and I need to store the data in a MYSql Database.

How would I go about doing this?
I need  to store 52 week based on date values in the  database. 
Also this website currently has a captcha installed in it.

How would I bypass the captcha and should I make 52 columns of data for storing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good way to try is to use urllib2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html that webpage probably uses cookies to check if you are done that captcha step, so do that captcha part first manually, get all the cookies etc and use urllib to mimic real browser and user. If that doesn't work then you can try to bypass the catpcha, by finding for example a json file that allows you to pass values(in an url) to server and which then sends the correct json file to you.

Comment: I need to automate this process of getting this Json Data.
There are currently 800+ links that I have to get the data from.
Also, the data from the links are updated weeekly. I need a way o store the links based on a specific date condition and then store something around 50 json values for each link.

Answer (score 0):

I actually accomplished this using Selenium or HTMLAgilityPack and Regular Expressions. I retrieved the DOM for the page and then using Regular Expressions parsed the document till I found the required data. Once that was done,the data was stored in a variable and the data was used. My language of choice was C#.